# Measuring treatment effect when the dosage is not under your control

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mixed-model, experiment-design, stratification

I'm running an ab test for an on-demand service where one group receives compensation in response to poor service, while the other group does not. The hypothesis is that "compensating for poor experience has a measurable effect on reorder rate". However, I don't know how to control for the variation that not all customers in each group will experience the same quality of service - they could vary by number of orders in observation period and number of poor service experiences, as well as potentially other features. It seems like the effect of compensation should control for these variables, but I don't know how to do that? Would it be possible to analyse various subgroups within the datasets? Or should I fit some kind of model?